# Debugger that supports debugging programs in multiple languages

Tags: debugging

Is there a debugger that supports debugging programs written in C, C++, Java, PHP, Python, Javascript, Bash shell scripts all at the same time? Otherwise, what debugger exists for each of the languages mentioned?

Is lldb extendable with plugins to support debugging programs written in non C and non C++ languages?